# Create shortcut to a specific folder in the 'Send To' context menu?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, send-to

I want to add an item to the "Send To" context menu. The problem is that if I add an item there, let's say for example "C:\Users". When I drag the folder across Windows interprets that I want to copy the file in to that folder, but what I want is to create a shortcut on that folder, is there anyway to do that?

I know I can create a shortcut on desktop and the move it where I want. I'm just looking for a faster way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with standard Windows functionality. A homemade solution is needed here.

Download [Shortcut.zip](http://optimumx.com/download/Shortcut.zip) and extract it to C:\Windows\system32.
This program will allow us to create shortcuts.

Create a batchfile called 'sendToExample.cmd' with the following contents, don't forget to change 'targetfolder':

```
@echo off
:: change this to whatever you need
set targetfolder=d:\Temp
shortcut /f:"%targetfolder%\%~n1%~x1.lnk" /a:c /t:%1
```

Create a shortcut in your SendTo folder (%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo) to this batch file.

You're done! Shortcuts will automagically be created!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!!! I only edited "%~n1%~x1.lnk" to "%~n1.lnk", so the shortcut doesn`t create with the extension.