# Fastest way to adding program in Windows startup

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, windows-explorer

### 1. Description

In Google I can find only solutions, where I need in many steps for adding my program to Windows 10 startup folder. Are there fast ways? Example:

---

### 2. Expected behavior

For example, I have `SashaGoddess.exe` application:

1. <kbd>Right_Click</kbd> to `SashaGoddess.exe` in Windows Explorer or desktop,
2. Select `Send to startup`,
3. Shortcut for `SashaGoddess.exe` will be created and send to `shell:startup` — `C:\Users\SashaChernykh\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` for me.

---

### 3. Questions

- How to realize expected behavior?

or

- Other fast solutions? Built-in or gratis third-party applications.

---

### 4. Do not offer

1. Please, do not offer solutions from [**that How-To Geek article**](http://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/) or similar.
2. Please, do not offer solutions with many steps for adding programs in startup.

Comment: Are you looking to add the programs/shortcuts to specific individual startup folders, or everyone's startup folder?  For a specific user, the target would be `%SystemDrive%\Users\(User-Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.  To do the same thing for all users, the appropriate folder would be `%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: @Run5k, does not matter for me, both solutions are suitable for me. But maybe for other users suitable only one of the solutions. So I think it's better publish both, if you can realize it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Plan

1. **Write a script** to create a shortcut (`.lnk`) in `shell:Startup` folder using supplied parameter as shortcut target;
2. **Place** that script (*or its shortcut*) into `shell:SendTo` folder;

### Usage

For sample `SashaGoddess.exe` application on **two mouse clicks**:

- <kbd>Right_Click</kbd> `SashaGoddess.exe` in Windows Explorer or desktop,
- navigate to `Send to…` submenu (which should expand automatically),
- <kbd>Click</kbd> your script…

---

**Hint**

FYI, `shell:Startup` folder name equivalent in *native* Windows scripts is

- `"%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"` in `cmd`,
- `WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Startup")` in VBScript,
- `[Environment]::GetFolderPath('Startup')` in Powershell.

**Sample `.bat` script** (basic functionality):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

if "%~1"=="" goto :eof
if not exist "%~1"  goto :eof

set "_auxiliaryScript=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
set "_lnkFile=%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\%~n1.lnk"

> "%_auxiliaryScript%" (
  echo Set oLnk = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^).CreateShortcut^("%_lnkFile%"^)
  echo oLnk.TargetPath = "%~1"
  echo oLnk.Save
)
cscript //nologo "%_auxiliaryScript%"
del "%_auxiliaryScript%"
```

Comment: JozefZ, [**this script**](http://superuser.com/a/591759/572069) helped for me. Please, add script example in your answer, and I accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to copy the program/shortcut to a specific user's Startup folder, the target would be as follows:

```
%SystemDrive%\Users\(User-Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\​Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

To quickly access your *another* user's Startup folder, it may seem a bit remedial but I normally keep that same path name saved in a text file and paste it into File Explorer whenever I need it. As a result, if I want to copy a shortcut to a few specific users I can simply change the User field in the File Explorer address bar and quickly navigate to another person's Startup folder.

On the other hand, if you need to place that same program/shortcut into the Startup folder for all users on that computer, the appropriate location would be as follows:

```
%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

For future usage, if you want quick access to the Startup folder that applies to *all users*, you could use that same path to create a shortcut to that folder and have it readily available on your desktop, your Quick Access in File Explorer, etc.

Comment: Run5k, yes, I know it. But what I can do for quickly add applications to one of these folders? Thanks.

Comment: For the folder that applies to all users, there are potentially a few different methods.  Essentially, you could create a shortcut to that folder and have it readily available on your desktop, your Quick Access in File Explorer, etc.  For a specific user, I normally keep that same path name in a text file and paste it into File Explorer.  As a result, if I need to copy a shortcut to a few specific users, I can simply change the User field in the File Explorer address bar and quickly navigate to another person's Startup folder.

Comment: -1 from me. The user clearly asks for a method. They want to learn HOW to do it quick, not where the paths are. The quickest way to go to one's startup folder is typing shell:startup in the address bar anyway.

Comment: @LPChip , good feedback and I am glad to expand my answer.  Regarding your second point, I would tend to agree… however, the OP emphasized to *"Please, do not offer solutions from that How-To Geek article"*, and the shell:startup method was specifically mentioned within that article.  Since he went out of his way to stress that point, I wanted to respect his wishes.

Comment: Run5k, I don't think that your solution it allows users to spend less time for add programs in startup than solution on How-To Geek. Thanks.